# Prism 7 UWP Windows 10 IoT How to project setup and use Modules

Tags: uwp, prism, windows-10-iot-core

**Target:**

I used Prism 6.3.x for WPF applications and now i'm faced with rabbit prototyping a Windows 10 IoT UWP application and I would like to use the Prism.Windows 7 Framework without Xamarin.

**Problem:**

I know Prism 7 is under development, but pre-release is available and I studied the breaking changes.

1. Are there actual Templates for Prism.Windows (UWP, no xamarin) available?
2. Is it possible to use Modulebased Design for Windows10 IoT and DirectoryModuleCatalog, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both those questions is no. We are in the process of aligning features such as Modules into the core Prism assembly to be shared across platforms, but we have not completed that work yet.  Currently, Prism for UWP is stale, and it won't be until Prism for UWP v7 when any of those items will be available.

Comment: Now that v7 is out, does Prism support UWP on Windows t0 IOT?